# Swift 3: Control landscape status bar and navigation bar appearance

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

On an iPhone (compact) in landscape mode the status bar is hidden and the navigation bar height is less than in portrait.  How can you prevent both of these behaviors with Swift 3 iOS 10?  I have seen a number of answers but the solutions appear to have been deprecated in current releases.

Comment: Not judging or anything, but I'm curious as to why would you want iPhone SE users to look at your app through a slit 

Comment: It's a fair point.  I guess I'd have to see how it will look before deciding if it makes sense.